# Main Menu Editor Problem

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I'm new to Raspberry Pi (I have a 3B+ with Bookworm 64bit) and have customized the Main Menu quite a bit. Now it starts reverting back to default randomly after a certain while. How can I fix this - and if there is no good solution, where is the configuration file saved so that I can make a backup and simply restore it next time instead of spending a lot of time to restore my custom settings manually?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: questions should have a question mark on the end ... please correct your post

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Bookworm is not currently recommended for Pi3.

Comment: I originally had Bullseye installed, which had the same problem. Was hoping the problem would disappear after upgrading, but it didn't. Otherwise, Bookworm seems to run smoother than Bullseye...